# Gmail log out security issue?

Tags: firefox, gmail, logout

I have formatted the hard drive disk in my computer and I have forgotten to log out from my gmail account before (logged in using firefox in my PC). Now I cannot access the gmail account because I do not recall the password and therefore cannot do the log out. My question is if this could be a security issue and somebody could access my gmail account? I only used my PC for accessing gmail.

Comment: "My question is if this could be a security issue and somebody could access my gmail account?"  - They would need to have your password to do this.  If you are really worried, enable 2FA on your Google account, that way only somebody with access to the Google authenticator can gain access to your Google account.  Of course you have to recall your password, if you want to do that, without the password you will be uinable to access your account.

Comment: Before formatting the hard drive disk in the pc I have never been asked to enter the password when using the gmail account. Now I am worried that this is a security issue because I did not logged out.

Comment: " have never been asked to enter the password when using the gmail account." - This is because you saved the password within the password manage of the browser.  "Now I am worried that this is a security issue because I did not logged out." - **It is not a security issue.**

Comment: When I do not use the password manager - is it still a problem e.g. if cookies are used?

Comment: You might not have been aware you saved the password, but you did, based on the fact you didn't have to type the password to log into the account.  Your account is safe, only somebody with the password can access it, as been proven by your inability to access the account without it.  **Your concern is not warranted.**

Comment: There is nothing saved to the computer that is easily obtained that would contain your Google password to answer your question. If you forgot the password use the password recovery options Google has otherwise move on and don't worry.

Answer (score 1):

There is no security issue, other than you forgetting your password.

When you login to gmail, the passwordhash is stored locally in a cookie, and that is being used to log into gmail on each visit.

When you format your pc, you destroy that cookie too, so there is no way someone else can login to your gmail account. Logging in is an event that happens on your pc. Even if you remained logged in, you automatically are being logged out after you close your browser. Its just this cookie that automatically logs you in once you open the browser again.

So no, there is no issue, except that you now need to use the "I forgot my password" mechanism if you ever want to get access to your gmail account again.